# Why does this work in DrRacket but not in Racket from the console

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme, racket, the-little-schemer

```
(define pick
    (lambda (num lat)
      (cond ((null? lat) (quote()))
            ((= (sub1 num) 0) (car lat))
            (else 
                  (pick (sub1 num) (cdr lat))))))
(define brees (quote (a b c d e touchdown g h i)))
(pick 6 brees)
```

The language in DrRacket is set to Advanced Student.  It also works fine in the IronScheme console after defining `sub1`.

The error message is:

```
reference to undefined identifier: R
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I assume that these are separate runs.  I would make sure that you have the latest version of racket, and if it persists, ask on the plt mailing list or file a bug.  The PLT people are about as responsive a crowd as you will find.

Your crash is occuring in the REPL code, but I have no idea where R comes from.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll do a bit more research and then ask the PLT people if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I type this into the console I get

```
Welcome to Racket v5.0.
> (define pick
    (lambda (num lat)
     (cond ((null? lat) (quote()))
        ((= (sub1 num) 0) (car lat))
        (else
              (pick (sub1 num) (cdr lat))))))
> (define brees (quote (a b c d e touchdown g h i)))
> (pick 6 brees)
'touchdown
```

How are you running this in the console?  If you are loading it, you may need a `#lang Racket` for the first line.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong.  It seems to work now.  I was just running Racket on windows by running racket.exe and entering everything into the REPL.  Weird.  Thanks.

Comment: I cannot find where I've seen this, but I think racket uses by default the latest #lang you've used in the past. That may explain this erratic behavior.